# Detect if object was created with a custom prototype design pattern?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm working on logic that detects any stateful variables that can be safely saved and restored via JSON as the storage vector.

Part of this means detecting types that are "safe" to dump and restore, which is easy for:

- numbers, strings and booleans (via `typeof`)
- Array elements (via `instanceof Array` combined with ^ in iterated elements)
- ES6 Class instances (via `typeof` object and `value.__proto__.constructor.name`)

There is one type I'm struggling with though. It's the one created from calling:

`var nn = new convnetjs.Net();`

Which comes from this: 
https://github.com/karpathy/convnetjs/blob/master/src/convnet_net.js#L8

What's interesting is that Chrome dev tools detects this as a "Net" object:
[image: nn]

This is what you'll see if you inspect the `nn` var shown above.

Here's what I've tried:

- `nn instanceof Object` === true
- `Object.getPrototypeOf(nn)` - interestingly, this exposes the functions assigned to `Net.prototype` in the link above, line 12 onwards. Seemed like a lead.
- `Object.getPrototypeOf(nn).toString()` == `[object Object]`
- `Object.getPrototypeOf(nn) instanceof Object` === true. Makes sense, since it's an object containing custom functions attached to the prototype.
- `Object.getPrototypeOf(nn).constructor.name` === `Object`

Would anyone know or have ideas how I could detect this type of object safely? Plain objects are fine, but I don't want to overwrite objects with modified prototypes.

Comment: `[Number, String, ...].includes(Object.getPrototypeOf(nn))` ? Or am I missunderstanding something here?

Comment: There is no (detectable) difference between `class`es and `function`s used as constructors, except that `Test()` without `new` throws for `class`es

Comment: Aha, this seemed to work - at least as a check whether it's a plain object (without the added prototype functions): `Object.getPrototypeOf(value) === Object.getPrototypeOf({})`. Would still love for a way to read "Net", just like dev tools manages, but at least I have a way of detecting unsafe objects of this particular type!

Comment: `nn.constructor.name` ?

Comment: @JonasWilms that was my first guess too, sadly: `value.constructor.name === 'Object'`

Comment: Then it doesn't inherit a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If resorted to using this to verify it this is a plain object or one with custom prototypes:

```
const isPlainObject = Object.getPrototypeOf(value) === Object.getPrototypeOf({});
```